# Siri is draining my battery since upgrading to iOS 11

Tags: ios, battery, siri

A few weeks back I upgraded finally from iOS 10 to 11 (I got an Apple Watch so had no choice if I wanted to use it).  Ever since then, my battery life has gone to crap on my iPhone SE.  The worst culprit is apparently Siri.  I've found other questions such as [this one dealing with the same thing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219758/i-dont-ever-use-siri-but-its-using-too-much-battery), but the proposed solution seems to be inconclusive since others have the same problem with different "solutions", and also I actually use the suggested apps quite often so don't want to disable them anyway.

Why on earth is Siri suddenly consuming so much battery since upgrading, and what can I do about it?  Is it related to Siri use on the Watch?  I do use Siri there quite a lot as it's extremely convenient, but it's not like I dictate books or something... just the odd short iMessage or Skype reply.

**EDIT:  After disabling Hey Siri for a couple of days, my battery drain has slowed way down and Siri is only a very small part of it.  I'm not convinced however that this is actually the culprit however because this had never happened before.  I've turned it back on now and will see if anything changes again.**

Comment: Siri is part of the home screen suggestions, Apple Watch faces and probably has ties to spotlight. Do you disable them and spotlight and Siri to be sure you aren’t using it more than expected? Turn off hey Siri too, to be sure it’s Siri.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot frankly because I do actually use Siri regularly.  But prior to iOS 11 she was never any significant portion of my battery usage.  I'm not sure why Apple Watch would have anything to do with Spotlight though... it's not like I'm searching my phone from the watch or anything, right?  I'll try turning off Hey Siri for a day and see if anything changes.

Comment: I can make a non-answer. It will be - contact support, then do these things to see if you can isolate which part is burning CPU. I think you get that picture though already.

Comment: Yeah in my experience Apple Support is very, very, *very* rarely helpful at all.  I generally will call them just on a lark once I have well & truly exhausted every other conceivable troubleshooting step.

Comment: If you can get them to run diagnostics, engineering will get the details even though you’ll never hear about it. If you opt in to sharing usage data with Apple, that’s good, too.

Comment: Yeah I'm only interested in what solves the problem for me personally.... once upon a time I worked there myself but these days I don't have any direct personal contacts on the inside.